# Question about ex-dividend date timing

Tags: stocks, dividends, ex-dividend-date

For example, if the ex-dividend date is next Monday, and I buy the stock on next Monday, would I get the dividend? Or would the person who sold the stock to me get the dividend?

Comment: ...and would it depend on what time of the day the stock purchase occurred as compared to what time of the day the dividend was declared?

Comment: Time of day would make the process awful, imagine the folk using a live broker, and waiting on hold.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the definition of [Ex-dividend date from the SEC](http://www.sec.gov/answers/dividen.htm):

> Once the company sets the record date, the stock exchanges or the National Association of Securities Dealers, Inc. fix the ex-dividend date. The ex-dividend date is normally set for stocks two business days before the record date. If you purchase a stock on its ex-dividend date or after, you will not receive the next dividend payment. Instead, the seller gets the dividend. If you purchase before the ex-dividend date, you get the dividend.

The linked document discusses weekend, and holidays involved in the calculation.

The difference between the record date and the ex-dividend is to allow for the three days of settlement.

Comment: +1 ex-dividend can be confusing at first, but if you think about it the name makes sense. The ex-div date is the first date on which the stock is bought/sold "ex[cluding]"-dividend.